# StaleElementReferenceException in FindElements(By.TagName(“a”)))

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I save site links with the following code, but in some sites, I encounter the following error:

OpenQA.Selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: "stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document (Session info: chrome=xx.x.xxx.xx)"

problem with (this site): https://namnak.com

```
private string followlinks(string url)
{
    IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\");

    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);

    //...
    //...
    //...

    foreach (var item in driver.FindElements(By.TagName("a")))
    {          
        var url2 = item.GetAttribute("href");
        //...
    }
```